# REISUB (Alt+SysRq+key) doesn't work on Slackware13.37_64, KDE

Tags: slackware, magic-sysrq

Under Slackware I never used the magical REISUB, and never used KDE (I don't know if it is important). But now I installed a Slackware13.37_64 with KDE, and, as far as I know, I didn't modify anything that could modify the default REISUB behaviour. Well, it didn't work in a disastrous situation. I tried then it with the system functioning well, and it didn't work either. Is it a bug or a disabled feature? How to switch it on?

`$ uname -a`

`Linux mysystem 2.6.37.6 #3 SMP Sat Apr 9 22:49:32 CDT 2011 x86_64 Pentium(R) Dual-Core CPU       T4300  @ 2.10GHz GenuineIntel GNU/Linux`

The notebook is ASUS K50IJ.

Comment: For those unaware like me: [The `REISUB` magic sysrq key sequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_SysRq_key#.E2.80.9CREISUB.E2.80.9D_.E2.80.93_safe_reboot)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently, [it can be enabled/disabled using `/proc/sys/kernel/sysrq`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_SysRq_key#Disabling_SysRq_key) if the kernel supports it, i.e., `CONFIG_MAGIC_SYSRQ` is enabled in the kernel config [what should be the case for Slackware, according to this](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/slackware-14/why-is-config_magic_sysrq-enabled-by-default-865708/).